# A word for a depiction within a depiction?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm conducting an experimental study using paintings. In a small selection of paintings, it is possible to see painting in the background too. I.e., paintings within a painting.

For experimental reasons, we are interested in that which is depicted on the 'real' painting, and not in what is depicted on the paintings within the paintings.

Is there a word, or phrase that would fit the following sentence?

"We are interested in the main painting, but not in the [...] paintings."

Comment: In the absence of any more specialized word, I would just use "We are interested in the main painting, but not in the *background* paintings."

Comment: I'm not sure "painting" is necessarily an appropriate term for your context. Probably better to refer to ***primary*** and ***secondary*** (or ***background, incidental,*** etc.) ***images***.

Answer (score 2):

The "main painting" (an odd term, because there is only one painting) includes any small painting in the background, as in the example of a self-portrait of an artist in the studio, in which there is a painting on the easel, or an interior scene in which there is a wall with a painting hanging on it. I would call the entire painting itself "the painting as a whole," or even simply "the painting," where the sense is clearly obvious from the context. One could also use the title of the painting to mean the painting as a whole. The smaller image is a "painting-within-the-painting." If you are interested in the painting, then surely the painting you are concerned with is the painting in its entirety, including the small painting on the wall or easel. What is depicted in the painting includes what is depicted in the small painting (which often has significance, as in Dutch art). But naturally, when you speak of the painting, you don't mean the painting-within-a-painting unless you specify that. So you are concerned with a painting of an interior of a home, say, with one or more figures, plus the furnishings (including any art in the painting). If your interest specifically *excludes* the painting-within-a-painting for some reason, you would have to say so: "We are interested in the composition [or content of the painting, etc.] as a whole, without attention to details of the furnishings."

Answer (score 0):

complete painting

embedded painting or picture

We are more interested in the whole paintings (or in general) then the embedded one.